# Receive multiple multipart/form-data properties with the same name in Spring WebFlux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, multipartform-data

On the frontend we have a form which send the data as multipart/form-data and we need to receive the data in the controller, and there could be a couple of records for the same property

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ids"

30
-----------------------------313589022531437741264012237550
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ids"

225
-----------------------------313589022531437741264012237550
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ids"

226
-----------------------------313589022531437741264012237550
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ids"
```

How to receive these values in the controller?

```
@PostMapping(value = "/create", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public Mono<String> create(@RequestPart("ids") List<Long> ids) {
// ...
}
```

`List<Long>` and `Long[]` doesn't work.

The request

```
MultipartBodyBuilder bodyBuilder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
bodyBuilder.part("ids", 22);
bodyBuilder.part("ids", 33);

webTestClient.post()
        .uri("/create")
        .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(bodyBuilder.build()))
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus().isOk();
```

The error

```
org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebInputException: 400 BAD_REQUEST "Failed to read HTTP message"; nested exception is org.springframework.core.codec.DecodingException: JSON decoding error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer>` from Integer value (token `JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_INT`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer>` from Integer value (token `JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_INT`)
 at [Source: (org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DefaultDataBuffer$DefaultDataBufferInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver.handleReadError(AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver.java:224)
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver.lambda$readBody$3(AbstractMessageReaderArgumentResolver.java:190)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94)
```

Here's a repo to demonstrate the problem:

https://github.com/alxxyz/spring-request-part-demo

Comment: From the stacktrace, it looks like Jackson is parsing an `Integer` but your code is expecting an `ArrayList<Integer>`. Consider creating a minimal sample showing the problem and share it here.

Comment: @JanNielsen you can find the request sample in the topic

Comment: @JanNielsen please find the sample https://github.com/alxxyz/spring-request-part-demo

Answer (score 1):

If you form your IDs as an array, they will be handled corrected:

```
        MultipartBodyBuilder bodyBuilder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
        bodyBuilder.part("ids", Arrays.asList(22, 33));
        //bodyBuilder.part("ids", 33);

        webTestClient.post()
                .uri("/create")
                .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(bodyBuilder.build()))
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk();
```

Comment: The issue is that the request from the client is sending 2 records, not one record with an array, and this can not be changed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
import org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.Part;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

@PostMapping(value = "/create", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public Mono<String> create(@RequestPart("ids") List<Part> ids) {
  var utf8 = Charset.fromString("UTF-8");

  // Part.content() returns a Flux<DataBuffer>.
  // This returns "33":
  return ids.get(1).content().map(dataBuffer -> dataBuffer.toString(utf8)).next();
}
```

Comment: I need all IDs, not just the first one